# Typescript is not properly inferring types from intermediately defined types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I have the following type definitions.

```
type Triple<A, B, C> = A & B & C;
type First<T> = T extends Triple<infer A, infer _B, infer _C> ? A : never;
type Second<T> = T extends Triple<infer _A, infer B, infer _C> ? B : never;
type Third<T> = T extends Triple<infer _A, infer _B, infer C> ? C : never;

// Scene1: Correct behavior

type F1 = First<Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>>; // { x: number }
type S1 = Second<Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>>; // { y: string }
type T1 = Third<Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>>; // { z: boolean }


// Scene2: Seems to be a wrong behavior

type XYZ = Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>;

type F2 = First<XYZ>; // unknown
type S2 = Second<XYZ>; // unknown
type T2 = Third<XYZ>; // unknown
```

Can someone explain why in `Scene2`, the resulting types are `unknown`?
See it in action in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgSzAGwgHgIIBooCEcDCAfFALxQZQBke1UBA3AFCiRQBiCcAzsGjCXIwoEAB7AIAOwAm3WIhToEkgGYQ4FHMrUaA%20vijb1UXcSgB%20ClABcUSRABu65q2gBlCAGMA9jP6DYEXEpWXkkVDQjPWxDVWMDKJMzS1wbO0dnFnBoGAALLml-MkCxCRk5eHClOOitGpME%20uT6NPsnOGYmAHou%20m84OC9gKAAjCFyAQwcEfqYstnYARmLOHj5KxTQAbyhRW0kAVwBbMY0AXxwdkFteREkAcygLqB2AL1sR729UCcknoiI83cy3IHh8fg2ER2ezsx1OT0uUGuUFuykezzeHy%20Pz%20ZwBQNgINg%20TghUh6Gh%20zhxgxSJuwDu6MR71G2Igv3%20gLmPQ4-SgRwgOAA7nBfI8xpNprMCQANACaAC1iuTtrsqScaYjkaiHgiXlAWZ9vuzcUROq4OAAmFZcXhoeUKs1QHkHSQAa0k3iFkgJbmtoK8vkKDqdLvdnu9BJg-uJBXtitDvVdHq9PqAA).

Comment: Your "correct" behavior isn't reliable because `Triple<A, B, C>` is completely identical to `Triple<A&B&C, unknown, unknown>` and almost always identical to `Triple<C, A, B>`.  You can't rely on the compiler inferring `First<Triple<A, B, C>>` as `A`. If I told you "I added three numbers and got 6; what was the first one?", you couldn't reliably tell me, right?  The fact that it sometimes works is just an implementation detail, where the compiler pattern matches instead of fully calculating the type.  Does this make sense? I have to see if I can find an authoritative source for this.

Comment: I mean, there's [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--), but it deals only with the most degenerate case where `Foo<T>` does not depend on `T` at all (that's like saying "I multiplied a number by zero and got zero; what number was it?).  I'll see if I can find something more directly analogous.

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29657

Comment: What I find strange is that `infer FromUnion<T> = T extends (infer A | infer B) ? [A, B] : never` will generally produce `[T, T]` as an output, while `infer FromIntersection<T> = T extends (infer A & infer B) ? [A, B] : never` will generally produce `[unknown, unknown]` as an output.  Neither behavior is what you're looking for (you can't recover particular union or intersection members) but `FromIntersection` completely forgets everything about `T`.  I guess one should never write `infer A & infer B` but I can't find a source for why.

Comment: Let me know if you want any of this written up as an answer, if the existing answer doesn't suffice for you.

Comment: @jcalz Just one addition, I think we'll need to wrap `[]` to prevent Distribution in conditional types `FromUnion<T> = [T] extends [(infer A | infer B)] ? [A,B] : never` to produce `[T, T]`

Comment: I added [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29657#issuecomment-1114295595) to ms/TS#29657 but I don't know if it will be answered.

Comment: @jcalz But you know, if in case `Triple` is evaluated as a tuple of three items like so: `[A, B, C]`, Scene2 will work. I'm thinking, maybe when `&` is used to connect record types, the order is not preserved, so the compiler can't properly infer. But anyway, thank you so much for the explanation. It make sense that if a type is already evaluated, decomposing it by inferring won't be reliable.

Comment: The order is almost never (reliably) preserved in an intersection.  ( Intersections of call signatures are order-dependent. ). But it’s not just *order*, it’s that `A & B` is equivalent to `(A & B) & unknown`, so you can’t even rely on the *number* of types.  String concatenation is order dependent but I still couldn’t tell you which two strings were concatenation to get `"abcde"`.  The type `[A, B]` on the other hand is only equivalent to `[X, Y]` if `X` is `A` and `Y` is `B`. So that’s why it infers reliably.

Comment: Understood. I also realized that the tuple should work because ordering was preserved and typescript knows it. Realized it after properly reading your comments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72078955/6405109) and the [the one you posted in github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29657#issuecomment-1114295595).

Answer (score 1):

`Types` in typescript are based on set theory, hence the properties that apply there are also applicable to them.

Hence operators like `&` and `|` are `Commutative` in nature.
Which basically means their orders can be changed.

`A & B == B & A`

`A | B == B | A`

This basically means the typescript compiler has more flexibility and can change the order and position of the operands(types) positions.

And `infer` works when we have a fixed structure and positions defined over which we can ask the compiler to give us the value at the position.

```
type Triple<A, B, C> = A & B & C;
type First<T> = T extends Triple<infer A, infer _B, infer _C> ? A : never;
type Second<T> = T extends Triple<infer _A, infer B, infer _C> ? B : never;
type Third<T> = T extends Triple<infer _A, infer _B, infer C> ? C : never;
```

**In case 1** :

We are inferring the types from the type parameter of `Triple` while instantiating itself and hence we can get the types from those positions as typescript knows their actual place from where it should infer.

```
type F1 = First<Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>>; // { x: number }
type S1 = Second<Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>>; // { y: string }
type T1 = Third<Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>>; // { z: boolean }
```

**In case 2** :

We instantiated the type value first and hence know there is no certainty that the type will still be `A & B & C`.

Typescript can even store it and use it as `B & A & C` or `C & A & B` and other combinations.

So, the best guess it can come up with is the type of it is `unknown`
Hence the desired behavior

```
type XYZ = Triple<{ x: number }, { y: string }, { z: boolean }>;

type F2 = First<XYZ>; // unknown
type S2 = Second<XYZ>; // unknown
type T2 = Third<XYZ>; // unknown
```